# How to tell passenger to use another user instead of www-data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, capistrano, passenger

I have a rails 3 app running on a ubuntu 12 server with passenger & apache.  I am deploying my application using Capistrano, and have the following variables set...

```
  set :user, "deployer"
  set :use_sudo, false
```

If the deploy_to folder is owned by the deployer user, the files get deployed correctly, however passenger cannot start up because it is trying to access the files in the app folder which is owned by the deployer user.  I tried creating a new group and assigning www-data and deployer to that group along with the files, however this did not work, passenger still times out on startup.  I also tried setting all the files to something insecure like chmod 777, and still it is not working.  Also I tried setting the PassengerDefaultUser but that did not help after restart as well.  However if I chown the folder recurrsively to www-data it will boot up, but now capistrano cannot deploy to that folder since it's owned by www-data instead of deployer.

Is there a simple work around to get this working either on the passenger or capistrano side?  I am unsure what the www-data user password is so deploying using that user is not an option.

Answer (score 6):

In your config file change the settings [PassengerDefaultUser](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/apache/reference/#passengerdefaultuser) and [PassengerDefaultGroup](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/apache/reference/#passengerdefaultgroup) (if necessary)

```
PassengerDefaultUser deployer
```